# Google Calendar API App Script - "Error: Not Found: Skipping"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm using this App Script [Populate a team vacation calendar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/vacation-calendar)

I'm receiving the following error for 1 person in a Google Group of 50 users.

> 'Error retriving events for email@email.com, vacation:
> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.list failed
> with error: Not Found; skipping'

[image]

When setting a breakpoint, it fails on this import event.

```
function importEvent(username, event) {
  event.summary = '[' + username + '] ' + event.summary;
  event.organizer = {
    id: TEAM_CALENDAR_ID,
  };
  event.attendees = [];
  console.log('Importing: %s', event.summary);
  try {
    Calendar.Events.import(event, TEAM_CALENDAR_ID);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error attempting to import event: %s. Skipping.',
        e.toString());
  }
}

do {
  params.pageToken = pageToken;
  let response;
  try {
    response = Calendar.Events.list(user.getEmail(), params);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error retriving events for %s, %s: %s; skipping',
      user, keyword, e.toString());
  continue;
}
events = events.concat(response.items.filter(function(item) {
  return shoudImportEvent(user, keyword, item);
}));
pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
 } while (pageToken);
 return events;
}
```

This is the stack:

> "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.list failed
> with error: Not Found at findEvents (Code:111:34) at Code:48:20 at
> Array.forEach () at Code:47:14 a…"

This is the full code

```
// Set the ID of the team calendar to add events to. You can find the calendar's
// ID on the settings page.
let TEAM_CALENDAR_ID = 'CALENDAR ID';
// Set the email address of the Google Group that contains everyone in the team.
// Ensure the group has less than 500 members to avoid timeouts.
let GROUP_EMAIL = 'GROUP EMAIL';

let KEYWORDS = ['vacation', 'ooo', 'out of office', 'offline'];
let MONTHS_IN_ADVANCE = 3;

/**
 * Sets up the script to run automatically every hour.
 */
function setup() {
  let triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  if (triggers.length > 0) {
    throw new Error('Triggers are already setup.');
  }
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sync').timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  // Runs the first sync immediately.
  sync();
}

/**
 * Looks through the group members' public calendars and adds any
 * 'vacation' or 'out of office' events to the team calendar.
 */
function sync() {
  // Defines the calendar event date range to search.
  let today = new Date();
  let maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() + MONTHS_IN_ADVANCE);

  // Determines the time the the script was last run.
  let lastRun = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastRun');
  lastRun = lastRun ? new Date(lastRun) : null;

  // Gets the list of users in the Google Group.
  let users = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL).getUsers();

  // For each user, finds events having one or more of the keywords in the event
  // summary in the specified date range. Imports each of those to the team
  // calendar.
  let count = 0;
  users.forEach(function(user) {
    let username = user.getEmail().split('@')[0];
    KEYWORDS.forEach(function(keyword) {
      let events = findEvents(user, keyword, today, maxDate, lastRun);
      events.forEach(function(event) {
        importEvent(username, event);
        count++;
      }); // End foreach event.
    }); // End foreach keyword.
  }); // End foreach user.

  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastRun', today);
  console.log('Imported ' + count + ' events');
}

/**
 * Imports the given event from the user's calendar into the shared team
 * calendar.
 * @param {string} username The team member that is attending the event.
 * @param {Calendar.Event} event The event to import.
 */
function importEvent(username, event) {
  event.summary = '[' + username + '] ' + event.summary;
  event.organizer = {
    id: TEAM_CALENDAR_ID,
  };
  event.attendees = [];
  console.log('Importing: %s', event.summary);
  try {
    Calendar.Events.import(event, TEAM_CALENDAR_ID);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error attempting to import event: %s. Skipping.',
        e.toString());
  }
}

/**
 * In a given user's calendar, looks for occurrences of the given keyword
 * in events within the specified date range and returns any such events
 * found.
 * @param {Session.User} user The user to retrieve events for.
 * @param {string} keyword The keyword to look for.
 * @param {Date} start The starting date of the range to examine.
 * @param {Date} end The ending date of the range to examine.
 * @param {Date} optSince A date indicating the last time this script was run.
 * @return {Calendar.Event[]} An array of calendar events.
 */
function findEvents(user, keyword, start, end, optSince) {
  let params = {
    q: keyword,
    timeMin: formatDateAsRFC3339(start),
    timeMax: formatDateAsRFC3339(end),
    showDeleted: true,
  };
  if (optSince) {
    // This prevents the script from examining events that have not been
    // modified since the specified date (that is, the last time the
    // script was run).
    params.updatedMin = formatDateAsRFC3339(optSince);
  }
  let pageToken = null;
  let events = [];
  do {
    params.pageToken = pageToken;
    let response;
    try {
      response = Calendar.Events.list(user.getEmail(), params);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error retriving events for %s, %s: %s; skipping',
          user, keyword, e.toString());
      continue;
    }
    events = events.concat(response.items.filter(function(item) {
      return shoudImportEvent(user, keyword, item);
    }));
    pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  return events;
}

/**
 * Determines if the given event should be imported into the shared team
 * calendar.
 * @param {Session.User} user The user that is attending the event.
 * @param {string} keyword The keyword being searched for.
 * @param {Calendar.Event} event The event being considered.
 * @return {boolean} True if the event should be imported.
 */
function shoudImportEvent(user, keyword, event) {
  // Filters out events where the keyword did not appear in the summary
  // (that is, the keyword appeared in a different field, and are thus
  // is not likely to be relevant).
  if (event.summary.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase) < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!event.organizer || event.organizer.email == user.getEmail()) {
    // If the user is the creator of the event, always imports it.
    return true;
  }
  // Only imports events the user has accepted.
  if (!event.attendees) return false;
  let matching = event.attendees.filter(function(attendee) {
    return attendee.self;
  });
  return matching.length > 0 && matching[0].responseStatus == 'accepted';
}

/**
 * Returns an RFC3339 formated date String corresponding to the given
 * Date object.
 * @param {Date} date a Date.
 * @return {string} a formatted date string.
 */
function formatDateAsRFC3339(date) {
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssZ');
}
```

Comment: While links to external resources might be helpful, questions should be self contained. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén I revised my question with the code.

Comment: The code is uncomplete to be a [mcve], i.e. `params` is not declared and there are missing details about how to reproduce the error.

Comment: I went ahead and just added the whole code at the end. There isn't much to say other than the error 'Error retriving events for email@email.com, vacation: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.list failed with error: Not Found; skipping' happens every time it runs. For 1 specific user.

Comment: The question has a several problems. I suggest you to start from scratch. Focus the new question in a single error message, and include a [mcve] to reproduce that specific error. Include all the relevant details to allow others reproduce the error,  like if the users belongs to only one domain or to multiple domains, etc.

Comment: Does the user have access to the calendar? The  `error: Not Found` usually is related to permissions in Google calendar. You can read more about this [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/errors#404_not_found).

You can review the permissions of the calendar by following [these steps](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9282964#5.1) or using the method [Acl: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/acl/list).

Comment: @GiselleValladares the user is in a group that the shared calendar is using to read individual calendars so I would assume so? Is there something I can have the user check or give authorization to?

Comment: Which is the calendar where the events are created? Is it a secondary calendar or the calendar of someone else? If the calendar is a secondary calendar, the user with the error message it's subscribed to the calendar? (Note: they can review this if they access calendar.google.com, the user can see the calendar in the left panel under "My calendar" or "Other calendars" based on the information [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1626902?hl=en#:~:text=New%20group%20members%20do%20not%20get) )

Comment: This shared calendar is reading the person's personal calendar and looking for keywords such as 'OOO' or 'Out of Office' in their event titles to then populate itself. So since this person is in a group, the shared calendar is looking at the group calendar, looping through each person in that group, finding the keywords in their event titles, and populating itself with whoevers event matches the keyword. Everyone else doesn't have a problem and they didn't have to give access.

Comment: @Rubén is this better?